# Which is the best way to represent my data

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a following data structure:

```
Page0
    Key0
        Text
        Color
        Name
    Key1
        Text
        Color
        Name
Page1    
    Key0
        Text
        Color
        Name
    Key1
        Text
        Color
        Name
```

Which is the best data structure to use ?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Do you want to send it over the web, format raw data, etc...? Then JSON could be a good option.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what for?

Comment: I find Jason too verbose. The Application creates a user interface on an Android mobile using Wifi. The data is used to provide the various attributes for each  Widget.

Comment: Interesting app... Hash maps (like Python Dictionaries) are a good start, your data looks like a map in this case

Answer (score 1):

Options:

Tree
Nested dictionaries
Nested lists
Dataframe with multi-index
Custom classes (Class Page has attribute of class Key, class Key has attributes Text, Color, Name)

Which one is best depends on the use case, especially how you're going to be accessing it (both reads and writes). A dataframe with multi-index is the more "[cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cube)" like option. People who are into object oriented programming would probably go for the custom classes option. Nested lists/dictionaries are in some sense the "lightest" option, and are more amenable to export options such as JSON, and if your code accessing is itself nested loops, this may be a good match, but it may get unwieldy if you want to visually inspect the structure. Lists take up less space in memory, but can be slower to access, and aren't as nicely labeled.

Comment: If  I go with Custom classes, how would I access each attributes ?

Comment: @user1530405 Are you not familiar with accessing attributes in general, or is there something specific to this case? The name of Key0 of Page0 would be `Page0.Key0.name`.

Comment: Yes, I am. I did not formulate my question well. But I found that a dictionary within a list within a list is the best method for me. Ie. Pages[Keys[{Atttrs}]]. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a nested dictionary structure like this:

```
myThings = {
    "Page0": {
        "Key0": {
            Text,
            Color,
            Name
        },
        "Key1": {
            Text,
            Color,
            Name
        }
    },
    "Page1": {    
        "Key0": {
            Text,
            Color,
            Name
        },
        "Key1": {
            Text,
            Color,
            Name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of options, depending on your usage of the objects, and mainly on how you want to **access** the objects after they are created.
There is not one correct answer, and here are some optional guidelines.

Each of your objects (`Key`s and `Page`s) can be described as classes.

If your objects have methods that change their data than you can implement them as a `class`, but if they don't have methods, and just hold the info, you can implement them as `dataclass` (which has automatic generic method implementation).
If you really don't want a class and you don't have methods at all, you can put the data at a `namedtuple` or just a `dict`, but then you'll access the members of your objects by strings.

For accessing the objects after creation there are some options:

1. If you just want to hold the objects, and the order doesn't matter, that means that for each access you go over all of your objects, you can use a `set`.
2. If you are going to access your objects serially or their order does matter, you can put them in a `list`.
3. If each of your objects has a name (id) and you want to access each of the objects specifically, you can use a `dict`.

Of course there are more considerations, like runtime and memory, but that can be optimized after you chose the basics.

In your case you have to choose 2 collections - one for `Key`s for each `Page`, and one for all of the pages.

For example if the order of the keys in the page doesn't matter, but the order of the pages does, with the current information from ykur case, I would implement your classes as `dataclass`, and each `Page` will hold a `set` of `Key`s, and all of the `Page`s would be held in a `list` of `Page`s.